# How can I rewrite the query in the notation (+) from Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, join

How to rewrite the query in the notation (+) from Oracle, i.e.  what would happen without joins?

```
select  *
from    tbl1
left join (
                tbl2 join tbl3
                on tbl3.id = tbl2.a
                and tbl3.b = 50
            )
on   tbl1.id = tbl2.c
```

Comment: Why are you converting modern ANSI syntax to legacy proprietary syntax that was superseded 30 years ago?

Comment: Оld isolated systems still live

Comment: @TulaMan71, Oracle has supported ANSI SQL `LEFT JOIN` syntax [since version 9i](https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/ansi-iso-sql-support), released in in June 2001. Are you saying you're still using a version of Oracle more than 20 years old?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```sql
WITH t23 AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM   tbl2,
         tbl3
  WHERE  tbl3.id = tbl2.a
  AND    tbl3.b  = 50
)
SELECT *
FROM   tbl1,
       t23
WHERE  tbl1.id = t23.c (+)
```

or:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   tbl1,
       (
         SELECT *
         FROM   tbl2,
                tbl3
         WHERE  tbl3.id = tbl2.a
         AND    tbl3.b  = 50
       ) t23
WHERE  tbl1.id = t23.c (+)
```

However, stick with the modern ANSI syntax and don't use the confusing, legacy comma joins that were superseded 30 years ago.

Comment: In the Lorax's famous last word, "unless". There are a few features in Oracle that still require old join syntax (most notably, materialized views with refresh on commit); and many more situations where Oracle's internal transformation of ANSI syntax to old Oracle syntax (which is how Oracle implemented the ANSI syntax) is buggy. The same query with ANSI syntax throws errors (when the query is actually perfectly fine); after rewriting it with Oracle syntax, it does work perfectly fine. So, I agree - stick with ANSI syntax, unless...